# PHP accessing Incoming PUT Data

Tags: php, put

Is PUT similar to POST?

I'm getting some inbound requests (apache) with this:
[REQUEST_METHOD] => PUT

I've never worked with this request method before.  So I have to ask if I'm supposed to process it differently.

The people sending me data are claiming to be sending xml.  So my script has this:

```
<?php
if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    mail("me@myemail.com","some title i want", print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true)); 
}else{
    die("not post data");
}
?>
```

I'm stuck here now.  If there's a PUT request, do I replace $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA with something else?

Comment: Does `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` work for `PUT`, have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, tested it, and it doesn't seem to recognize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php), `PUT` data can be read using the [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) stream (which is preferred over `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`).

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
$str = stream_get_contents($putdata);
fclose($putdata);
```

Comment: Does that work for linux environments?  the php:// seems to be a windows thing.  I could be totally wrong there, but it's an assumption

Comment: You can also use `$str = file_get_contents('php://input');` as a more succinct alternative.